# Truffle not recognizing constructor size change

Tags: solidity, truffle

For some reason truffle is not recognizing the change in constructor size

Things I've tried

1) Uninstall truffle and reinstall
2) deleting the build folder and recompiling

When i run a test it complains but runs the test anyway

```
(node:97628) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Factory contract constructor expected 3 arguments, received 2
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-contract/contract.js:390:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-contract/contract.js:374:1
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
(node:97628) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:97628) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

the second time I run the test it crashes truffle, so I have to reboot truffle after I get one test to run.

```
Error: Factory contract constructor expected 3 arguments, received 2
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-contract/contract.js:390:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-contract/contract.js:374:1
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in my migrations folder I had not updated 2_deploy_contracts to use all three of the constructor arguments. It was hidden to me, because I was only running test testFile.js and didn't realize it ran this migration every time